# Find all matched selectors with RegExp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript to find all selectors using RegExp?

For example, how can I find all selectors `element1`, `element2`, ... `element21341234`?

```
document.querySelectorAll('.element + [regexp]')
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the regex, that a regular selector couldn't achieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve an array of elements. But I don't know their numbers. I know only first part of class - `element`.

Comment: Could you give us a clue as to what you're trying to match with this regular expression? A sample of the relevant HTML would be very useful (and, frankly, mandatory in a question involving CSS).

Comment: Ok. I know that class on elem is `.element[some number]`. but numbers is unknown for me. I need to find when in `DOM`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the information provided, I'd suggest:

```js
// using Array.prototype.filter, to filter the elements returned by
// 'document.querySelectorAll()'
var elementPrefixed = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('[class*=element]'), function(el) {
  // '\b' is a word-boundary,
  // 'element' is the literal string
  // \d+ is a string of numeric characters, of length one or more:
  return (/\belement\d+\b/).test(el.className);
});

// iterates over the found elements, to show those elements that were found:
[].forEach.call(elementPrefixed, function(el) {
  el.style.color = '#f90';
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  width: 50%;
}
div[class]::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="element1"></div>
<div class="element2"></div>
<div class="element3"></div>
<div class="element4"></div>
<div class="elementOther"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="2element"></div>
<div class="3element1"></div>
<div class="4element15"></div>
```

Alternatively, it's also possible to extend the `Document` prototype to offer a `document.getElementsByRegex()` method:

```
// adding a method to the Document.prototype:
Document.prototype.getElementsByRegex = function (attr, reg) {
  // attr: String, an attribute of the element you wish to search by,
  // reg: a RegExp literal which should perform the search.

  // here we find all elements in the document with the specific attribute:
  var superSet = document.querySelectorAll('[' + attr + ']');

  // if there are no elements with that attribute, we return null:
  if (!superSet.length) {
    return null;
  }
  else {
    // otherwise we return a filtered array, of those elements
    // which have an attribute matching the regular expression:
    return [].filter.call(superSet, function (el) {
      // we're using 'el.getAttribute(attr),' rather than el[attr],
      // because searching by class would require el[className], and 'for'
      // would require el[HTMLFor]; getAttribute irons out those kinks:
      return reg.test(el.getAttribute(attr));

      // Note that this method returns an Array, not a NodeList (live or otherwise)
      // unlike document.getElementsByClassName() for example

    });
  }
};
```

```js
// adding a method to the Document.prototype:
Document.prototype.getElementsByRegex = function (attr, reg) {
  // attr: String, an attribute of the element you wish to search by,
  // reg: a RegExp literal which should perform the search.

  // here we find all elements in the document with the specific attribute:
  var superSet = document.querySelectorAll('[' + attr + ']');

  // if there are no elements with that attribute, we return null:
  if (!superSet.length) {
    return null;
  }
  else {
    // otherwise we return a filtered array, of those elements
    // which have an attribute matching the regular expression:
    return [].filter.call(superSet, function (el) {
      // we're using 'el.getAttribute(attr),' rather than el[attr],
      // because searching by class would require el[className], and 'for'
      // would require el[HTMLFor]; getAttribute irons out those kinks:
      return reg.test(el.getAttribute(attr));

      // Note that this method returns an Array, not a NodeList (live or otherwise)
      // unlike document.getElementsByClassName() for example

    });
  }
};

console.log(document.getElementsByRegex('id', /\belement\d+\b/));
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto 0.5em auto;
  width: 50%;
}
div[class]::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="element1"></div>
<div class="element2"></div>
<div class="element3"></div>
<div class="element4"></div>
<div class="elementOther"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="2element"></div>
<div class="3element1"></div>
<div class="4element15"></div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-presence and value selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation).
  - [Substring-matching (`[attribute*=value]`) attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: elementOther, 2element, 3element1, 4element15 aren't valid elements.

Comment: And there is no possibility to change CSS>

Comment: You don't have to change the CSS, the CSS is there to show what was selected by the function, as are those specific elements; this is a demonstration. Had you shown your own HTML (as I requested) then I'd have worked with that. And, yes: the CSS names are valid (in HTML 5), they're just more difficult to select in CSS (they require escaping is all).

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll(selector)` takes a string as its `selector` argument, so you there's no way to just pass it a regular expression. If you need regular expressions, see [David Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26445844/436641).

However, you might not need a regular expression depending on your use case, as the string argument can be a comma-separated list of selectors.

So, if all you really want is `.element1`, `.element2`, and `.element3`, you can just pass them all in as a single string with each one separated by commas:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element1,.element2,.element3');
```

Comment: But I don't know the numbers (1,2,3) of elements. I mean for that reason maybe I can you regexp.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements' classes are `.element1`, `.element2`, `.element3`, and so on, you can try something like this:

```
// Create an array from 1 to 5
var x = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(function (_, i) {return i + 1;});
var elems = [];

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll('.element' + x[i]);
  elems.push(element);
}
```

Comment: I need to get an array of elems.

Comment: But I don't know total numbers (5 or something). I even can have elems `element1`, `element45` and `element8546`. So the number is unknown.

Comment: I don't know. There maybe five or 100. In fact the question is how to find them all. I need to find them with javascript.

Comment: Are they all `div` elements?

Comment: No. They could be any kind of elems.

Comment: And they are all `class`es, right? I mean no `id`s.